# Mariadb Dump download from command line

Tags: mysql, database-dump

i am trying to take dump of database using CLI mariaDb i am executing following query.

```
mysql -u root -p --database = byx_prod_db < dumpfile.sql;
```

i am getting this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump --add-drop-database  byx_prod_db > dump.SQL' at line 1
```

Comment: Examine your dump file with a text editor.  It was not created correctly, and seems to somehow contain the command line you used when trying to make a backup rather than the backup itself.